# UIView animations are getting removed when next controller is pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm using the code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^{
    [self.slidingDownImage setFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,
                                                rect.origin.y,
                                                rect.size.width,
                                                rect.size.height+100)];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
        [self.slidingDownImage setFrame:CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x,
                                                   originalFrame.origin.y,
                                                   originalFrame.size.width,
                                                   originalFrame.size.height+100)];
    }
}];
```

Its performed for swipe segue. But when I'm moving to the next controller, this animations are getting removed. I wish to save the view as it is (keeping animations) while transition to next view controller. Any ideas?

Comment: you mean self.slidingDownImage frame get reset again?

Comment: What do you mean the animation is being removed? Also, what is the desired effect if you DON'T push a new view controller? The code looks like you'd animate the view to it's new position (rect), and then when the animation completes,  the view would jump back to originalFrame without animation. What is happening without pushing a new VC, and then what happens, step by step, if you DO push a new VC?

Comment: When I swipe the animation is played and my view is resized. When I'm pushing next VC the view resets as before the animation. I wish to keep the animation while transition.

Comment: @pawan yes, you are rigth